# What would cause all the images to your site not to show?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image

I've been working on a site for a client, and I'm taking a recently changed design and incorporating that design into the existing site.  I was flipping back and forth between the two sites using firebug to compare the layout of the two.  Everything was showing up fine, and I didn't have any problems.

I stepped away from my computer for a second, and my son came into the room and did something on my computer, and 99% of the images that were showing up on the site are now not visible.  I'm not kidding. What images do show up are being set from data, and not from css or directly on the markup.

What is really weird is when I open up firebug and inspect the images firebug can actually see the image, and the img tags are showing up as disabled or something (they're greyed out).

Does anyone have any idea what might have been done and how I can fix this?

Other information:

The site is developed with ASP.NET MVC.
I'm not doing anything fancy, all img tags using src or background-urls are not showing.

Also, when I do a full get (without cache), I'm noticing in Firebug that it never does a get for any of the images that are not showing up.

If need be I can stand this up publicly so it can be looked at.

Comment: Is this like a 3 year old son that went bang-bang on the keyboard or a 16 year old son upset that he isn't getting the keys to the car this weekend?

Comment: 3 year old.. bang bang.. no more images =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.  Just in case any of you might have this happen to you.

Tools -> Options -> Content Tab

Make sure "Load images automatically" is checked off.

Click on Exceptions...

Make sure your site (in my case localhost) is not being blocked.

Yeah,.. gotta love kids.

Comment: Nice, my two year old is also quite adept at running to the keyboard and messing things up when I walk away for only a few seconds...